# How do I make this program work for input >10 for the USACO Training Pages Square Palindromes?

Tags: algorithm, search, adhoc

**Problem Statement -**

```
Given a number base B (2 <= B <= 20 base 10), print all the integers N (1 <= N <= 300 base 10) such that the square of N is palindromic when expressed in base B; also print the value of that palindromic square. Use the letters 'A', 'B', and so on to represent the digits 10, 11, and so on.

Print both the number and its square in base B.
```

INPUT FORMAT

A single line with B, the base (specified in base 10).

SAMPLE INPUT

```
10
```

OUTPUT FORMAT

```
Lines with two integers represented in base B. The first integer is the number whose square is palindromic; the second integer is the square itself. NOTE WELL THAT BOTH INTEGERS ARE IN BASE B!
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
11 121
22 484
26 676
101 10201
111 12321
121 14641
202 40804
212 44944
264 69696
```

My code works for all inputs <=10, however, gives me some weird output for inputs >10.

**My Code-**

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

int baseToBase(int num, int base)  //accepts a number in base 10 and the base to be converted into as arguments
{                                  
    int result=0, temp=0, i=1;

    while(num>0)
    {
        result = result + (num%base)*pow(10, i);
        i++;
        num = num/base;
    }

    result/=10;
    return result;  
}

long long int isPalin(int n, int base) //checks the palindrome
{   
    long long int result=0, temp, num=n*n, x=n*n;

    num = baseToBase(num, base);
    x = baseToBase(x, base);

    while(num)
    {
        temp=num%10;
        result = result*10 + temp;
        num/=10;    
    }   

    if(x==result) 
        return x;
    else
        return 0;
}

int main()
{       
    int base, i, temp;
    long long int sq;
    cin >> base;

    for(i=1; i<=300; i++)
    {
        temp=baseToBase(i, base);
        sq=isPalin(i, base);

        if(sq!=0)
            cout << temp << " " << sq << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**For input = 11, the answer should be**

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
6 33
11 121
22 484
24 565
66 3993
77 5335
101 10201
111 12321
121 14641
202 40804
212 44944
234 53535
```

While my answer is

```
1 1
2 4
3 9
6 33
11 121
22 484
24 565
66 3993
77 5335
110 10901
101 10201
111 12321
121 14641
209 40304
202 40804
212 44944
227 50205
234 53535
```

There is a difference in my output and the required one as 202 shows under 209 and 110 shows up before 101.

Help appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you give the problem link? here you are printing `temp` value meaning the value after converting to base `B`.  And your base conversion isn't correct i guess cause for `i = 240` your calculated temp is 209 while for `i = 244` temp is 202 for `B = 11`. that's why it's printing 209 first then 202.

Answer (score 0):

a simple example for `B = 11` to show error in your base conversion is for `i = 10` temp should be `A` but your code calculates `temp = 10`. Cause in we have only 10 symbols 0-9 to perfectly show every number in base 10 or lower but for bases greater than that you have to use other symbols to represent a different digit like `'A', 'B' and so on`. problem description clearly states that. Hope You will be able to fix your code now by modifying your `int baseToBase(int num, int base)`function.